# Google Analytics API "ga:day" dimension and more than 1 month of data returns aggregate instead of absolute values

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

I am attempting to retrieve Google Analytics daily visitor counts. I'm following [this blog post](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/02/mastering-unique-visitors-in-api.html).

For under 30 days of consecutive data, everything works great. The problem is that the result rows get "grouped together." Consider this query:

```
    { ids: 'ga:44339606',
  'start-date': '2013-01-01',
  'end-date': '2013-02-14',
  dimensions: 'ga:day',
  metrics: 'ga:visits',
  segment: 'gaid::-1' }
```

The values returned for days 01 -14 are incorrect, because they actually represent the sum of January 1st + February 1st, and the sum of January 2nd and February 2nd, and so on. In other words: there is only one entry returned for each day of the month, 1-30, instead of returning 44 entries.

How can I adjust for this, without breaking the query into multiple calls?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out, I wanted the `ga:date` dimension instead of `ga:day`
Check out the playground; it's great for figuring out params: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Comment: Hi! Did you get number of visitors for each day in the output with all dates?

Comment: @KristofferAndersson not each day

Comment: @koffe14 I want last 7 days datas. how can I extract it?